# I am having trouble combing the hair downwards. Is there a reason why it won't let me? Using the Empty Hair curve system on blender 4.0.2

Tags: modeling, particles, weight-painting, hair

[image]

You can see where the strands are placed, yet I am having trouble combing them down.
[image]

I tried fixing the weight paint but still left with the same result.
[image]

[image]